# Loose/fuzzy bin packing - minimizing overhead

Tags: combinatorics

I have a sequence of *n* random numbers, with a mean of *m*. How can I order them in a sequence seq a way that minimizes the following expression?

$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n  \left|\frac {\sum_{j=1}^i seq(j)}{i}-m\right|
$$

In other words, it's somewhat like bin packing but we can overflow as soon as we have minimum error and the "error function" is the sum of distances from the mean of all the sub-sequences that start from seq's beginning.

Some Python:

```
# find seq that minimizes error
averages = [ avg(seq[0:end]) for end in range(0,n) ]
error = max(abs(mean - min(averages)), abs(mean - max(averages)))
```

And as a picture...

[image: minimizing the error]

... The horizontal scale is the *i* on the sum above. As *i* approaches *n*, sum approaches the mean and error approaches 0.

Comment: Without the moduli (abs) this would be an ILP... so still NP-hard. With the abs the objective function is only piece-wise linear so even "harder". Actually just linear programming with [PLFs](http://www.mit.edu/~jvielma/presentations/PWL_DOS_08.pdf) (not restricted to integers) is still NP-hard. I don't know if this particular problem has an easy solution.

Comment: Yes. It feels like there should be an easy solution of grouping sets of large under-the-average numbers with sets of over-the-average numbers in a flexible way. But the Devil is in the detail.

Comment: Well, if the input numbers were equally distanced i.e. an arithmetic progression, and if the inner sum were taken only for even-length [sub]sequences (instead of all lengths), then I think you can easily give the optimal solution in the way you indicate.

Comment: Even for arithmetic-progression inputs, with the objective function from the problem-statement, for the odd-length subsequences intuitively you have to do "throw in" a number close to the middle of the (whole) input sequence (thus close to the mean).

Comment: By the way, there's a new SE beta site http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ where numerical solutions (to optimization problems etc.) are the main focus. So you may have better luck there.

Comment: Thank you all guys. :) NP-hard I guess - is the answer I'm looking for. With 2-3 seconds of monte carlo I get something acceptable for practical uses. Obviously not "the optimum" but good enough.